# Hackerrank SQL challenge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This T-SQL query

```
SELECT city, Len(city) 
FROM station 
ORDER BY Len(city)
```

returns table sorted by `city`, not by `Len(city)` - is this proper behavior?

```
Acme 4 
Addison 7 
Agency 6 
Aguanga 7 
Alanson 7 
Alba 4 
...
```

The challenge is :

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5

Comment: My that's wonderful!  Now, what have you tried and why isn't it working?

Comment: I fail to see why that would return sorted by `city` as opposed to `Len(city)` as defined in your query...

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior in SQL Server 2016 - works as anyone would have guessed - the query returns the rows sorted by **length** of the city's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want first and last, I'd probably just use a union and top 1.  makes it clear as to what you're after and easy to maintain.

And since you can use alias in order by... I'd alias len(city)

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    city, len(city) LenCity 
FROM 
    station 
ORDER BY
    LenCity ASC 

UNION ALL 

SELECT TOP 1 
    city, Len(City) lenCity 
FROM 
    station 
ORDER BY 
    LenCity DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to my GitHub if you have any problems with the other questions. These are the answers to all the Basic questions. Feel free to join in!

https://github.com/jaymoore3/SolvingHackerRank/tree/main/SQL/Basic

Buuuuutttt... If you just need the code:

```
    select city,len(city) as LengthOf
    from station
    group by city,len(city)
    having len(city)=(select max(len(city)) from station)
    union
    select top 1 city,len(city) as LengthOf
    from station
    group by city,len(city)
    having len(city)=(select min(len(city)) from station)
```